# SSH: Can I always trust a remote server with dynamic IP?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have a server that I need to connect to sometimes. It has a public IP, but the IP is renewed quite often. To combat that, I have a script that will update a DNS record to map ssh.myurl.com to my new IP.

This setup works, but once the IP changes, I get the error:

> WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!

Then I have to delete the key from my client, using `ssh-keygen -R ssh.myurl.com`, and it works again.

But this seems redundant, as I can't really see how this adds any security. Can I configure this setup so that it always trusts this connection?

The setup is using `ProxyJump` if that would change anything.